# why is " docker build ." failing with "ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11"

Tags: docker

```
(venv) PS D:\DESK\desktop\django code\Django_Docker_with_PostgreSql> docker build .
[+] Building 1.0s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                     docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 215B                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11                                                                                                                                                           0.9s 
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM python:3.11
   2 |
   3 |     ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: python:3.11: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from POST request to https://auth.docker.io/token: 403 Forbidden
```

Restarted docker and laptop. Sign in and sign-out docker.
This is an initial new project.
nothing has worked for me

Comment: Something is causing you to fail your connection to docker hub.

Comment: reauthenticate, do docker login